# How to extend GitKraken commit summary length

Tags: commit, gitkraken

I would need to have a larger commit summary size, if someone is wondering why, it's for having a more descriptive summary to make it easier to spot and understand what was done and why in the commit tree, by someone who is unfamiliar with the ticket. This is more for cross review commits than anything else.

The default summary length is 72 characters, is there a way to extend this limit?

Comment: Git itself imposes no length limit on the summary line, but most *humans* would like it not to exceed mid-50s-characters in length. Longer descriptions are generally considered to belong in the body of the commit message. Is there some way to do that here? That would work better with the rest of the ecosystem. (As for changing any length limits that GitKraken itself imposes, I have no idea—I don't use GitKraken.)

Comment: @torek I agree with everything you say, the fact of the matter is that it is company requirement to have these more descriptive and long summaries, the use of gitkraken is just because I like to use it, it's not part of the company toolchain so I can't complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, unfortunately.

I submitted an idea - https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/232964/allow-customization-of-summary-character-length - to capture the discussion.